# Is it OK to delete old tweets about events that are no longer relevant?

Tags: online-interaction, public-issues, netiquette

Here's some context:

- the twitter account is owned by an organisation
- they post content infrequently
- some of the tweets are referencing an old event that is no longer relevant; people who go on the twitter account can see those tweets (and the event)
- there is other content further down the feed which is more relevant

**Is it "good manners" to delete outdated tweets ?**

Please assume that creating more new content is not practical for various reasons.

The intent here is to curate an accurate image of the organisation. Too many tweets about past event is not helping with that. I think it's better if visitors only see tweets that are aligned with the company's vision.

Comment: Hey Mars, you are asking about etiquette (which is fine here) however, I don't see how your question is about interpersonal communication. Could you maybe clarify that? In the meantime, I'm voting to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by all twitter account I came across that write about "current events" they don't go and delete old ones.
You can go to news twitter and read about issues from  years ago that were written as "this is happening now". You can go to celebrity tweeter and read about their attendance to some events that is long gone.
I would even says that deleting old tweets is bad manners because it's looked as removing evidence of past activities. There would be no reference but information that there was a reference that is now removed.

Comment: `because it's looked as removing evidence of past activities` why would that be bad manners?

Comment: @JAD it would be assumed that what you are removing is something discriminatory (because why would you remove "great time at cochela" tweet). And that would mean that you are a person who rather deny existence of problem rather than explain or discuss about it.

Answer (score 0):

I delete comments, or posts on Facebook for the following reasons:

- It didn't *perform* well.
- It was a temporary thought and now I don't want people to see it for reasons like, it is stupid, might be rude too or simply because I don't want people to associate it with me.

It's about how someone wants to use a platform.

Now as the question has

> other content further down the feed is more relevant

So yeah, clean up is recommended!

> The intention is the curate an accurate image of an organisation.

If the tweets are not coherent with the current image of organisation, I would second deletion.

For the sake of history-keeping(for both visitors and employees), an external archive can be made and linked to.

<sup>Didn't expand the last point, as I don't want to answer *What should you do?*</sup>